# How to link a Shiny App uploaded in the browser and a Rmd?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinyapps

I have developed a shiny app with some sections which produce some results. There is another section with the option of download, in HTML format, the plots done in the app. When I am in the R environment it works, but it works because i have the shiny app file .R and the R markdown file .Rmd in the same folder. But when I upload the app in the browser, this link between the shiny app and the r markdown is lost. Is there a way to link both so someone without the Rmd document and without even having R Studio downloaded can use the app and download the plots in an HTML?

I am trying to find some option in shinyapps.io (i guess there's the place where they can be linked) but with no success. Thank you.

Edition: I'm trying something like that https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html

But in this example, it doesn't matter where and what is the R Markdown file?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. Being in the RStudio environment, when one want to publish the app, in the window "Publish to Server", in the box "Publish Files From", there must be the two files, the .R file where the shiny app code is and the .Rmd where the code for the HTML download is.